# Can I compare against multiple strings with the equals() method?

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to get multiple strings with .equals?

```
if(something.equals("String1 String2 String3")){
   System.out.println(Something);
}
```

What I mean is:

```
if(choose.equals("DO IT")){
   sysout blah blah blah
}
else if(choose.equals("DONT DO IT")){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, but an alternative for many strings is to put the strings in a collection and do something like:

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();
strings.add("A");
strings.add("B");
strings.add("C");

if (strings.contains("D")) {
  // ...
}
```

which is perhaps a little more concise. It's also null-safe wrt. the string you're looking to compare, which is often very useful.

Note further with Java 7 [the switch statement works with strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html), and that's useful if you wish to tie different actions to different strings.

Answer (score 5):

If something is `"String1 String2 String3"` then it is equal.

If you mean contains, you can do

```
List<String> valid = Arrays.asList(string1, string2, string3);

if (valid.contains(something))
```

Comment: Perhaps a `HashSet` or `TreeSet` is better, since `contains` operations are done - on average - in *O(1)* or *O(log n)*

Comment: @CommuSoft For three elements a Set can be slower. As the number of elements get above say 8, Set wins out.

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot. `equals()` takes only one object at a time.

As an alternative, you can try something like

```
if(something.equals("String1") || something.equals("String2") ||       
                                                 something.equals("String3")) {
   System.out.println(Something);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "can I test a string being equal to several strings in one operation", use regex:

```
if (something.matches("String1|String2|String3")) {
    System.out.println(Something);
}
```

The pipe char `|` means "OR" in regex.

Note that in java (unlike many other languages) `matches()` must match the *whole* string - ie this is an "equals" comparison, not a "contains" comparison.

Comment: Shouldn't you surround the regex with `^` and `$`?

Comment: @CommuSoft no. with `matches()`, `^` and `$` are *implied*. Adding them has no effect. See the last point of my answer. try it  for yourself - see if `fooString` or `String1foo` matches (it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex given the strings you match don't contain special regex characters, or are escaped.

**Example**:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(String1|String2|String3)$");
if(p.matcher(something).find()) {
    //do something
}
```

---

Or you can store the strings in a set/list and query the set:

**Example:**

```
HashSet<String> possible = new HashSet<String>();
possible.add("String1");
possible.add("String2");
possible.add("String3");
if(possible.contains(Something)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use `||` to test multiple strings for equality:

```
if(something.equals("String1") || something.equals("String2") || something.equals("String3"))){
   System.out.println(Something);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have gone through the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) it says

`public boolean equals(Object obj);` :

**Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.**

**It does not says that some other object is "equal to" these Objects.**

Using `equals()` you can compare an `Object` with some other `Object`. It does not allow you to compare at once an `Object` with many other Objects. However if you want to compare an `Object` with many other `Objects` then you will need `equals()` for each comparasion

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to check if there are any in such a string that don't match (aka all must match, albeit that doesn't really seem to make sense to me), then

```
String initString = "String1 String2 String3";
String[] splitStrings = initString.split(" ");
boolean match = true;
for(String string : splitStrings)
{
    if(!string.equals(something))
    {
        match = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(match == true)
{
    //did match all of them
}
else
{
    //there was one that was not matched
}
```

If you want a "matches at least one" then it's just

```
String initString = "String1 String2 String3";
String[] splitStrings = initString.split(" ");
boolean match = false;
for(String string : splitStrings)
{
    if(string.equals(something))
    {
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(match == true)
{
    //did match at least one of them
}
else
{
    //didn't match any of them
}
```

But to be honest, Java 8 makes this simpler:

```
String something = "whatever";
String initString = "String1 String2 String3";
String[] splitStrings = initString.split(" ");
boolean matchAll = Arrays.stream(splitStrings).allMatch((x) -> x.equals(something));
boolean matchAny = Arrays.stream(splitStrings).anyMatch((x) -> x.equals(something));
```